# Android Twitter login failed with Twiter4j

Tags: android, twitter4j

I am using twiter4j 3.0.3 for integrating Twiiter to my application.I have used following code for login. It was working before.Now it throws an exception while trying to login. Log cat is attached.

```
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            Configuration configuration = builder.build();

            TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
            twitter = factory.getInstance();

            try {
                requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
                isSuccess = true;
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                isSuccess = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Logcat

```
 01-22 12:06:27.666: W/System.err(2581): 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
01-22 12:06:27.666: W/System.err(2581): Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
01-22 12:06:27.666: W/System.err(2581):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=bfb606ed or
01-22 12:06:27.666: W/System.err(2581):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=4ef9707c
01-22 12:06:27.666: W/System.err(2581): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[bfb606ed-4ef9707c], statusCode=403, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}
01-22 12:06:27.666: W/System.err(2581):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:177)
01-22 12:06:27.666: W/System.err(2581):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
01-22 12:06:27.666: W/System.err(2581):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:98)
01-22 12:06:27.666: W/System.err(2581):     at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:122)
01-22 12:06:27.666: W/System.err(2581):     at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:104)
01-22 12:06:27.666: W/System.err(2581):     at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:281)
01-22 12:06:27.666: W/System.err(2581):     at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:273)
```

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade your twitter4j jar from twiter4j 3.0.3 to twiter4j 3.0.5  its a new release .